# Throwing Exception out of annotation

Tags: java

I have an annotation on a method M in which I am making some checks, if the checks doesn't succeed I do not want to execute the underlying method M. I want the caller to know that the call didn't succeed along with the reason.

To achieve this I am throwing an exception out of annotation if checks fails. So here I have a couple of questions:

1. I am unable to catch the specific exception because the IDE tells me that exception is not being thrown out of the method? 
   For a quick hack I am catching `Exception` and then get to the specific Exception by using `instance of` operator.

   Is there any other better way to achieve this?
2. Do I have a way in which I need not throw the exception?

Annotation aspect code looks something like this:

```
@Before(value = "@annotation(abc)", argNames = "pjp, abc")
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ABC abc) throws Throwable {
       if(notAllow()){
            throw new CustomException("Not allowed");
        } else {
          pjp.proceed()
       }

    }
}
```

The handler code looks something like this:

```
catch(Exception e){
   if(e instanceof CustomException){
       // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you doing this? Java doesn't throw exceptions as a result of annotations - you need some kind of library with bytecode transformation to do that; which one is it?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Updated the question. Not sure if it is allowed, I am able to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE can only verify *checked* exceptions. Make the exception extend `RuntimeException`.

You can `catch` that any time you want, because the IDE cannot verify if any code throws it, since methods are not required to declare if they do.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the exception was a checked one. Anyway, do you think throwing exception is the only way?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Throwing exception is the only way to let caller know that method wasn't executed.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja that's precisely the problem. The exception is a checked one. Your method doesn't declare that it throws the exception. So the compiler doesn't allow catching this checked exception: it's never supposed to be thrown, since it's not declared in the throws clause. But the aspect, intercepting the method call, breaks the contract of the method by throwing a checked exception that is not declared in the throws clause of the method. The compiler can't know that the method is intercepted that way at runtime, and that you're violating its contract.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your time. When I felt I am unable to do it properly, it felt like I am doing something wrong. Should I not do such a task in an aspect? Or how can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: An aspect is fine, but if it throws a checked exception, then this exception should be declared in the throws clause of the method. But a runtime exception is a much better solution.